# How to inject `resolve` into a callback?

Tags: node.js, promise, closures

I want to combine middlewares in express to make them parallel, as opposed to sequential if you put the in `app.use(path, /* middlewares *,/ callback)`.

I write the following function:

```
function makeParallelMiddleware(args) {
  let makePromises = (req, res) => args.map((func) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('In promise: ' + func.name);
      func(req, res, resolve);
    })
  });
  return (req, res, next) => Promise.all(makePromises(req, res)).then(next())
}
```

But this does not seem to work properly. I test with the following two middlewares:

```
function middlewareA(req, res, next) {
  req.A = 1;
  console.log('I am in A');
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('I am in A delay');
    if (req.C) {
      req.C = 'BA'
    } else {
      req.C = 'A'
    }
    next()
  }, 1000)
}

function middlewareB(req, res, next) {
  req.B = 1;
  if (req.C) {
    req.C = 'AB'
  } else {
    req.C = 'B'
  }
  next()
}

app.get('/parallel', makeParallelMiddleware([middlewareA, middlewareB]) ,(req, res) => {
  res.send(req.C);
});
```

When I access `/parallel`, I can only get "B" instead of "BA".

How can it be possible that the promise is resolved before `req.C` is set? How do I correct this to get the desired result?

Comment: `then(next())` should be `then(next)`.

Comment: If you want to go down the promise route, you should make your middlewares return promises. If for some reason you still need callbacks, you can't just pass `resolve` around, as failing works differently with promises. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) how properly get a promise from node-style callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
return (req, res, next) => Promise.all(makePromises(req, res)).then(next())
//                                                   remove parens here ^^
```

to this:

```
return (req, res, next) => Promise.all(makePromises(req, res)).then(function(results) {
    next();
});
```

You were calling `next()` immediately rather than passing a function reference that can be called later by the `.then()` method.  Also, `next()` probably doesn't like an array to be passed to it which is what `.then()` would pass in your case, so better to just wrap in a custom function and just call plain `next()`.

---

And, you also need some error handling if either of your promises rejects which they could if they throw an exception.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `next` doesn't like to be called with an array as the first argument. Try `.then(next.bind(null, null), next)` instead.

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, I wondered what would happen in that case.  I've edited.